# Conflict with two home controllers but in different web projects?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have to mvc projects at the min using home in the admin site I just need the customer to be able to go to /admin

However the compiler is giving the following error

> Multiple types were found that match the controller named 'Home'. This
>   can happen if the route that services this request
>   ('{controller}/{action}/{id}') does not specify namespaces to search
>   for a controller that matches the request. If this is the case,
>   register this route by calling an overload of the 'MapRoute' method
>   that takes a 'namespaces' parameter.
>
> The request for 'Home' has found the following matching controllers:
>   solitude.admin.Controllers.HomeController
>   solitudeWebMvc.Controllers.HomeController

So I tried the following in my RoutesConfig.cs of the admin project

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
 routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

   routes.MapRoute(
    "Admin_default",
    "Admin/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    new { action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
    new[] { "AppName.Areas.Admin.Controllers" }
);
}
```

However I am still presented with the same error as above does anybody have any ideas. I am using multiple mvc web projects one for admin and one for front end. When deployed these will be on separate ports.

[image]

Comment: Separate projects deployed as separate applications definitely shouldn't have this problem.  Do the projects reference each other in any way?  (They shouldn't, but should be able to reference common code in class libraries.)

Comment: Hi @David I have a reference to solitude. admin in solitude webmvc is that not correct. However it has this issue in visual studio are you saying it wont have this problem on different ports and no people its not me talking to myself lol

Comment: The application projects shouldn't reference each other, no.  If they need to share common code, that code should be moved to a common class library which the two projects reference.  As soon as one of the application projects references the other, it's going to try to load the code for *both* projects into that one application.  So it's finding both controllers and unable to distinguish between them.

Comment: @David during testing will i still be able to pick up the controls on the same local host port ?

Comment: @David do you think its better to sep the admin and the front end in the long wrong I was trying to follow how nopComemrce achieves this

Comment: I can't speak to whatever nopCommerce does, as I'm not familiar with that.  It's not clear what you mean by "separate the admin and the front end" either.  If you have separate applications, then keep them separate.  You certainly can organize your applications however you like.  "Admin" functionality can be in the same application as "no-admin" functionality, or it can be in a different one.  That doesn't really inherently matter.  But if it *is* in a different application, then that application needs to be separate.

Answer (score 2):

According to a comment on the question:

> I have a reference to solitude. admin in solitude webmvc

Your application projects shouldn't reference each other.  Consider the structure when they do:

```
Application1
  -> Reference to Application2
Application2
```

When you compile and run these, `Application2` will be fine.  But `Application1` now has all of the code for *both* applications.  So when the framework examines that code it's going to find those conflicting controllers and be unable to distinguish between them.  You don't want *all of the code* from `Application2` to be in `Application1` like that.

Instead, consider a structure like this:

```
Application1
  -> Reference to ClassLibrary1
Application2
  -> Reference to ClassLibrary1
ClassLibrary1
```

Any shared code, ideally as objects with no dependency to application-level framework resources, would be in `ClassLibrary1`.  Both of the applications can reference that class library project to make use of that shared code.  But the application instances themselves should be independent of one another.

Answer (score 0):

If you could post both of the configurations for the two projects together, that would be great, but from looking at the config as you've posted, it's specifying a namespace which isn't directly related to the project.

`"AppName.Areas.Admin.Controllers"` as the namespace specification looks to be incorrect (and a simple copy & paste error), because your namespace for the two projects should be `"solitude.admin.Controllers"` and `"solutideWebMvc.Controllers"`

In addition, it looks like you may also have a misconfiguration of IIS, thus when you deployed to /admin, the child application is trying to use the binaries from the root folder and the ones from the /admin folder.

I realize this isn't a perfect answer, but you will need to provide some additional pieces of information to allow us to help you out further.